# uninitialized local variable

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, local, initialization

This code compiles and runs though gives a Microsoft compiler error that I cant fix

warning C4700: uninitialized local variable '' used.

This is in the last line of the code, I think

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int DIM0 = 2, DIM1 = 3, DIM2 = 4, DIM3 = 5;

void TestDeclar();

int main(){
    TestDeclar();
    cout << "Done!\n";
    return 0;
}

void TestDeclar(){        
    //24 - array of 5 floats
    float xa[DIM3], xb[DIM3], xc[DIM3], xd[DIM3], xe[DIM3], xf[DIM3];
    float xg[DIM3], xh[DIM3], xi[DIM3], xj[DIM3], xk[DIM3], xl[DIM3];   
    float xm[DIM3], xn[DIM3], xo[DIM3], xp[DIM3], xq[DIM3], xr[DIM3];
    float xs[DIM3], xt[DIM3], xu[DIM3], xv[DIM3], xw[DIM3], xx[DIM3];

    //6  - array of 4 pointers to floats
    float *ya[DIM2] = {xa, xb, xc, xd}, *yb[DIM2] = {xe, xf, xg, xh};   
    float *yc[DIM2] = {xi, xj, xk, xl}, *yd[DIM2] = {xm, xn, xo, xp};
    float *ye[DIM2] = {xq, xr, xs, xt}, *yf[DIM2] = {xu, xv, xw, xx};

    //2 - array of 3 pointers to pointers of floats
    float **za[DIM1] = {ya, yb, yc};    
    float **zb[DIM1] = {yd, ye, yf};

    //array of 2 pointers to pointers to pointers of floats
    float ***ptr[DIM0] = {za, zb};   
    cout << &***ptr[DIM0] << '\n';  
}
```

Comment: That program looks fine to me, but I don't have MSVC to check with.  Good luck!

Comment: When I compile I get: `warning C4189: 'ptr4D' : local variable is initialized but not referenced'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing past the end of the `ptr4D`. `DIM0` is 2, one greater than the last index of 1!

Change the last few lines to:

```c
//array of 2 pointers to pointers to pointers of floats
float ***ptr4D[DIM0] = {za, zb};   
cout << &***ptr4D[0] << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can help you but I tried to find out what's wrong trying to run it on my linux machine. I've compiled it on a ubuntu machine to compare and it went ok, even tellign the compiler to turn on all option warnings (passing the -Wall option). When running, I got this:

```
# Compiled it with -Wall to enable all warning flags and -g3 to produce extra debug information
~$ g++ -Wall stackoverflow.cpp -g3
./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I've tried to debug it with GDB (GNU debugger) and got this:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/ubuntu/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400986 in TestDeclar () at stackoverflow.cpp:34
34          cout << &***ptr4D[DIM0] << '\n';  
(gdb) s
```

So it appears that the problem is at the cout line. Checking your code again, *DIM0*'s value is *2*, so you're trying to access a memory address beyond the ptr4D. As [user1721424](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721424/user1721424) mentioned, just replace the *DIM0* with *0* and it's done!

```
#After fixing it:
~$ ./a.out 
0x7fff74cd3830
Done!
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ops, my bad, you've update it before I answered. Edited for clarification!